# list of libraries and functions that are used in multitouch android programming

Tags: android, multi-touch

i am in final year of computer engg. and this year i have taken up my project as developing an android app with description as follows:
1. user uses 6 fingers to first make an impression on the screen which is marked
2. the area's are then marked and numbered
3. when user next time places 2-3 fingers simultaneously in any area previously marked, some calculation is made based on which areas he places his fingers on.
4. based on this calculation , a caracter is displayed on the screen

its basically a type of multituch keyboard which is
-dynamically 1st positioned by the user
-and based on which dots are pressed, a character is selected

BRAILLE IS WHAT THIS ACTUALLY ABOUT....

I HAVNT STARTD YET... i am very good  coder in c/c++ java even won compettions at college level, but have no idea about how to program basic app in android which takes multiple input..

plz give sm suggestion or help regaurding this...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to look at gestures and multitouch.

You can find more information about Android gestures here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html

There might be some libraries you can use like android-multitouch-controller here
http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/